# custom tokens in AzureAD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have registered an application in Azure AD , And I need to include some determined/customized attributes in the token means I need to get customized token.

So for example I need to have attribute called "X" :

My steps so far is :

1- Created an extension property with type string through
POST : [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{App](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/%7BApp) Obj ID}/extensionProperties
Payload: {"name":"x","dataType":"string","targetObjects":["User"]}
Response:
"name": "extension_(generated ID number)_X",

2- I have registered a user:
POST: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Payload:{
"accountEnabled": true,
"displayName": "test",
"mailNickname": "testtest"
"userPrincipalName": "test@test.onmicrosoft.com",
"passwordProfile" : {
"forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false,
"password": "random pass"
}
}

3- I need to set the value of X for this user and have it as part of the returned customized token
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{userID}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BuserID%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)

How can I customize a token in Azure AD and set this X value

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the token type you want you should follow one of the below solutions:

For SAML:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-claims-customization

For WS-Fed, SAML, OAuth, and OpenID:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping